# IP forwarding. UDP chat

Tags: udp, ip, ip-address, forwarding

I wrote client/server chat using UDP on a local host and it works just fine. Then I sent my server via Skype to my friend, and he told me his IPAddress, and it's also worked fine. When I tried to send him client program, and told him my external IPAddress, he couldn't connect to me. And I tried it with different PCs, unsuccessful. What could be a problem of this?

Comment: Routers, NAT, Firewalls...

Comment: Can he ping your IP address..? Which port are you using?

Comment: Yes he can ping. I'm using 50000 port.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the site and still in school but I'll try to answer this best I can.

Going from localhost to outside public network means that you need to open the right ports on your router.  So a router can block the port or the computer's own firewall can block the port.  Check your router (and any intermediate hops between you and the internet) and check that box's own firewall (iptables on Linux, etc.).  Also means that your ISP has to support your use of those ports and forward them through it's own network.  That's why a simple http port 80 webserver will typically be available without much more than opening the router.  Whereas a mail server on port 25 is sometimes blocked, due to the use of malicious use of that traffic in spamming, open relays, etc.  The block is not necessarily both ways and traffic can go one way on a port but not the other -- it's possible.

So let's say that outside your LAN they can see your webserver, but can't see this other chat application. If you've open the right ports, then you might want to find out from your ISP what ports are open and blocked.

You just added that you're using port 50000.  Is this your home network? At school or a corporate network?  High ports are sometimes blocked to stifle torrent activity.  Again check with your ISP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, have a question how to find out which ports are open or blocked? It's my home network, and I used this port in my server, to get a connection from a client. I tried to use different ports >1024, and it is still not working.. Interesting sing that client on my PC can connect to host from another country, but client on host from another country can not connect to server on my PC.

Comment: As for using >1024 -- mainly like a VPN port, https, RDP, or similar is typically supported (or 8080 for alternate http), and peer-to-peer sharing still uses the higher ports successfully.  What ports have you tried using?  Who's your ISP?  What other country(ies) are you talking about?  What ISP are they using over there?  Sounds like there's a lot of hops in between to consider here.

Comment: I think it's not a problem of ports, and ISP, the ports are implemented in hosts, they connected processes on the hosts, routers cares only about network layer, data-link layer and physical layer, but ports are implemented in transport layer. I could be wrong. I tried using different kinds random ports, that are > 1024, since <1024 it's well known predefined ports. I think the problem is with some kind of forwarding of IP.

Comment: That's why I asked what country you're in and the country of other computer, and what ports the ISP's of both networks are blocked (if any). That IP address could've been black-listed recently before DHCP from your ISP gave you another (unless you have static, which is rare for home servers). Will the client connect within your own country?

Comment: No, I'm from Denmark, tried to connect with friends from Czech Republic, Kazakhstan, Russia. But why I could connect to them, and otherwise it's not working?

Comment: Denmark? I was thinking about graduate studies at U of Copenhagen. I'm in Florida, you can fry an egg on the pavement in summer. Anyhow, I'd be interested if they see your http webserver (just anything, apache or anything forwarded on port 80). If so, then your IP address is probably OK. If not then the IP could be an issue and just get another.  If not then, as I said twice, check what ports your ISP and their ISP's are blocking or forwarding.  If you can connect then ports may only be forwarding outbound.  Again, if you list all the ports you've tried that would be helpful.

Comment: Oh nice, it's really cool here, so i suggest you to study here:) Ok i will try to figure it out.  I tried to use 50000, 1300, 1345, 1200, 48765, 30007, 28000, etc...

Comment: Asked the professor today, he said that the problem is NAT of the router, probably it isn't configured to do translations.